# Trim text using sed

Tags: sed, awk, grep

How do I remove the first and the last quotes?

```
echo "\"test\"" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'
```

The above is working as expected, But I guess there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the `sed` calls into one:

```
echo "\"test\"" | sed 's/"//;s/"$//'
```

The command you posted will remove the first quote even if it's not at the beginning of the line. If you want to make sure that it's only done if it is at the beginning, then you can anchor it like this:

```
echo "\"test\"" | sed 's/^"//;s/"$//'
```

Some versions of `sed` don't like multiple commands separated by semicolons. For them you can do this (it also works in the ones that accept semicolons):

```
echo "\"test\"" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you prefer something like this:

```
echo '"test"' | sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure there are no other quotes besides the first and last, just use `/g` modifier

```
$ echo "\"test\"" | sed 's/"//g'
test
```

If you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ echo $s
blah"te"st"test

$ echo $s | ruby -e 's=gets.split("\"");print "#{s[0]}#{s[1..-2].join("\"")+s[-1]}"'
blahte"sttest
```

Note the 2nd example the first and last quotes which may not be exactly at the first and last positions.

example with more quotes

```
$ s='bl"ah"te"st"tes"t'
$ echo $s | ruby -e 's=gets.split("\"");print "#{s[0]}#{s[1..-2].join("\"")+s[-1]}"'
blah"te"st"test
```

Comment: tr -d \" is preferred over sed 's/"//g'

Comment: @kurumi Speed.  Using tr will be about twice as fast.  Sure, in many cases that is irrelevant, but tr is a good tool to know.  (It is similar to the 'y' command in sed.)

Comment: @william, sure. `tr` is good tool to know. but `sed` has many more uses than `tr`.

Comment: @kurumi Yes, sed does have more uses.  But when your goal is to remove all instances of a single character from a datastream, tr is the correct tool to use.

Comment: @William, i do not want to argue with you on this. Its OP's preference so my answer caters to that. For my own, I don't even want to use the myriad of shell tools available. Ruby is my first choice.